# Typeorm how to get relations of relations

Tags: mysql, typeorm

I am getting the Object ChatRoomEntity with `entitymanager.findOne` method. The ChatRoomEntity has the variable `messages` which is a OneToMany - ManyToOne Relation. I have no problems to select that but how do I get the user which sent the message. Its a variable on MessageEntity with a OneToMany Relation.

So basically I want to select a room and all messages of it. But all messages should also have their values on `fromUser`.
I select the room like this:

```
this.entityManager.findOne(ChatRoomEntity, {where: {id: roomToJoin.id}, relations: ['activeUsers', 'messages']}).then(roomEntity => {
// some code
}
```

Here my entities:

UserEntity

```
@Entity()
export class UserEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  registrationDate: Date;

  @ManyToMany(type => ChatRoomEntity, room => room.activeUsers, {cascade: true})
  @JoinTable()
  activeChatRooms: ChatRoomEntity[];

  @OneToMany(type => ChatRoomMessageEntity, msg => msg.fromUser)
  chatRoomMessages: ChatRoomMessageEntity[];
}
```

ChatRoomEntity

```
@Entity()
export class ChatRoomEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column('varchar', {nullable: true})
  title: string;

  @OneToMany(type => ChatRoomMessageEntity, chatrmsg => chatrmsg.chatRoom)
  messages: ChatRoomMessageEntity[];

  @ManyToMany(type => UserEntity, user => user.activeChatRooms)
  activeUsers: UserEntity[];

}
```

ChatRoomMessageEntity

```
@Entity()
export class ChatRoomMessageEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column('varchar', {nullable: true})
  message: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  creationDate: Date;

  @ManyToOne(type => UserEntity, user => user.chatRoomMessages)
  fromUser: UserEntity;

  @ManyToOne(type => ChatRoomEntity, chatRoom => chatRoom.messages)
  chatRoom: ChatRoomEntity;

}
```

Answer (score 106, accepted):

We can load sub-relations by using `'relation.subrelation'` within the `relations` array itself like this:

`relations: ['relation1', 'relation2', 'relation2.subrelation1']`

So for your case, instead of using join you can simply do something like this:

```
this.entityManager.findOne(ChatRoomEntity, {
        where: {id: roomToJoin.id},
        relations: ['activeUsers', 'messages', 'messages.fromUser'],
      }).then(roomEntity => {
...
```

This is specified here: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/find-options.md#basic-options

Comment: i have got issue when i remove the entity with fetched relation, please read this one its very much related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74302343/nest-2637-11032022-42850-pm-exceptionshandler-null-value-in-column

Answer (score 36):

#### Using QueryBuilder

```js
await getRepository(UserEntity)
   .createQueryBuilder('user')
   .leftJoinAndSelect('user.profile', 'profile')
   .leftJoinAndSelect('profile.images', 'images')
   .getMany()
```

#### Using FindOptions

```js
await getRepository(UserEntity).find({ 
   relations: ['profile', 'profile.images'] 
})
```

Comment: There can be performance issues with that approach. I've built my projects api using it, but it ended up crushing my app on every request. Read more [here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/4499). People in comments are suggesting to populate relations by separate queries.

Answer (score 7):

I did get the relations of the relation by setting it to true like this :

```
return await brandRepo.findAndCount({
    order: { updated_at: "desc" },
    skip,
    take: limit,
    relations: {
      products: {
        sizes: true,
        brands: true,
      },
    },
});
```

Answer (score 3):

**Update v0.4.0**

Typeorm is ditching `findOne`, you should use `findOneBy` for the queries without relations, and if you want relations, simply use `find`.

```
const users = await userRepository.find({
    where: { /* conditions */ },
    relations: { /* relations */ }
})

// users[0] if you want a first row
```

Comment: sorry man could you link us to where they said they were deprecating findOne?

Answer (score 1):

Next to the accepted solution, also this syntax is possible:

> relations: {activeUsers:true, messages: {fromUser: true}}

Answer (score 0):

here is the @gradii/fedaco orm how to implement this feature.
use can use multi relations by method `with`

```js
export class User extends Model {
  @HasOneColumn({related: Profile})
  profile;
}
export class Profile extends Model {
  @HasOneColumn({related: Image})
  image;
}
export class Image extends Model {
  name;
}
```

eager load

```js
User.createQuery().with('profile.image').get()
```

lazy load

```js
const user = await User.createQuery().first();
const image await (await user.profile).image
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add `loadEagerRelations: true` flag. So I'm adding it here in case someone runs into this.

```
this.entityManager.findOne(ChatRoomEntity, {
        where: {id: roomToJoin.id},
        relations: ['activeUsers', 'messages', 'messages.fromUser'],
        loadEagerRelations: true,
      }).then(roomEntity => {
...
```